# Private calls to API

Tags: rest, api, microservices

I have two microservices `registrations`, which is responsible for registering new users, and `users`, which hold information about users. Each of them has it's own database.

When a user tries to register, a call to `users` is made via the API, e.g.

```
GET users/verify?email=foo%40bar.com
```

to chech if the email has been already assigned to a profile. Although I could hide the access point `users/verify` in the public docs, it can still be accessible.

What is the best way to allow only private IPs make requests to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Gateway, some alternatives are

- [Tyk](http://tyk.io)
- [Kong](https://getkong.org/)
- [Netflix/Zuul](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/)

There is a nice article at https://thenewstack.io/api-gateways-age-microservices/

Comment: Kong looks really promising!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Do it at the firewall level

Whitelist the IP(s) that you want to be able to make requests, reject the rest

Comment: Yeah, probably I should save the IPs as env variables as well.